# C# DataReader not fetch any data from Oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, datareader

I am not able to get any data from an Oracle stored procedure in C#. But the stored procedure is running fine when running from SQL developer and is returning values.

I have tried several methods, but no luck. Below is the code snippet.

C# Code:

```
try
{
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(SP_TAXMASTER, con)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

    int intOpmode = 7;
    AssignmentParameterValues(cmd, ObjTaxMaster, intOpmode);

    con.Open();

    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


    while (dr.Read())
    {
        TaxMasterVO.TaxMaster objTaxMasterU = new TaxMasterVO.TaxMaster
                {
                    TaxCode = dr["TAX_CODE"],
                    TaxName = dr["TAX_NAME"]
                };
        // objTaxMasterU.TaxGroup = dr["TAX_GROUP"];
        objGenTaxMaster.GenTaxMaster.Add(objTaxMasterU);
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Parameter values in C#:

```
public void AssignmentParameterValues(OracleCommand cmd, TaxMasterVO.TaxMaster ObjTaxMaster, int opMode)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("P_OPMODE", OracleDbType.Int32, opMode, 200, ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("P_SALETYPE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 200, Equals(ObjTaxMaster.SaleType, null) ? "" : Convert.ToString(ObjTaxMaster.SaleType), ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("P_TAX_CODE", OracleDbType.Char, 200, Equals(ObjTaxMaster.TaxCode, null) ? "" : Convert.ToString(ObjTaxMaster.TaxCode), ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("P_TAX_NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 200, Equals(ObjTaxMaster.TaxName, null) ? "" : Convert.ToString(ObjTaxMaster.TaxName), ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("P_TAX_PERCENT", OracleDbType.Decimal, 200, Equals(ObjTaxMaster.TaxPercentage, null) ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(ObjTaxMaster.TaxPercentage), ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("P_TAX_ON", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 200, Equals(ObjTaxMaster.TaxOn, null) ? "" : Convert.ToString(ObjTaxMaster.TaxOn), ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("P_TAX_GROUP", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 200, Equals(ObjTaxMaster.TaxGroup, null) ? "" : Convert.ToString(ObjTaxMaster.TaxGroup), ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("P_STATUS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 200, Equals(ObjTaxMaster.TaxStatus, null) ? "" : Convert.ToString(ObjTaxMaster.TaxStatus), ParameterDirection.Input);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("CV_1", OracleDbType.RefCursor, 200);
    cmd.Parameters["CV_1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("O_TAX_CODE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 200);
    cmd.Parameters["O_TAX_CODE"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
}
```

Stored procedure in Oracle:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "SP_TAXMASTER" (
    P_OPMODE      IN NUMBER DEFAULT 4 ,
    P_SALETYPE IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    P_TAX_CODE        IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL ,
    P_TAX_NAME IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
    P_TAX_PERCENT IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
    P_TAX_ON IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
    P_TAX_GROUP IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
    P_STATUS IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,

    CV_1          IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    O_TAX_CODE OUT VARCHAR2
     )
AS
     V_TEMP     NUMBER;
     V_AUTO_NO  VARCHAR2(100);
     V_TAX_CODE   VARCHAR2(100);
     V_TEMP1    NUMBER;

    IF P_OPMODE = 7 THEN
    BEGIN
        OPEN CV_1 FOR 
             SELECT TAX_CODE,TAX_NAME FROM TAX_MASTER WHERE STATUS IN ('A');
    END;
    END IF;
```

I am not able to get any data from the `DataReader`, whereas in SQL Developer, the stored procedure is running fine and is returning rows.

Please suggest

Comment: are you getting any exceptions while calling SP from c# ? , Are you using any ORM like Entity framework ?

Comment: No.. I am not getting any exception on this. But Rows are returning Zero at data Reader.

Comment: just try this  con.Open();
   OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
   da.Fill(dt);  
  let me know if u r getting any data